# How to create user in mysql with sqlmap?

Tags: user-management, sqlmap

**Is it possible to create a mysql user using sqlmap? Look if the user is root@localhost, it would have all the permissions since this is dbm**

I tried some statements such as the execution of the CREATE command within the sql